# If I only want to set status and header in NodeJS response, do I need to call 'send('')'

Tags: node.js

```
return res
    .status(404)
    .set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

I am only interested in sending status code and header. I have no body or message. Is the above code valid, or I need to call send('') to complete construction the response object ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sendStatus(code) which will just send the status code without any attached json with response

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus

```
res.sendStatus(404);
```

or

```
res.status(404).end();
```

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end